# What stories for children have strong female role models?

Tags: education, history

I notice that just about all young children's stories (fairy tales, etc) depict women in a subordinate role. This hit me while reading Cinderella: her ultimate goal in life is to be the prettiest so that she can marry the rich boy and make babies. More generally, females are absent, or if present, they're following boys or performing household tasks.

Having two daughters, I can't help but think that they'll in some way absorb this cultural baggage. I would rather raise them to be self-reliant and independent, and ready to embrace desires other than cooking and finding a boyfriend. Can anyone recommend any good sources of beginner-level books/movies/etc that have a more egalitarian approach?

Comment: @Beofett Finding good role models for girls in literature is a very real problem for parents. I suggested an edit (that asked for reading lists instead of individual books) to get this question reopened, but apparently it was rejected. Literature is information, and as such is not a "product" in the same way a brand of shoes is. Can anything be done to get this question reopened?

Comment: @MaryJoFinch I agree finding a good role model for girls is a real problem for parents. The issue is questions that ask for open-ended lists are simply not a good fit for our format. If the question can be formatted in a way that can have fairly comprehensive answers that aren't subject to link rot (such as a list of web sites you can go to), and doesn't encourage a bunch of answers that contain just a single "try this one out!" answers, it would help.

Comment: I've reopened the question, but with the condition that it gets rephrased to avoid being "please give me a  list of titles" because that's not the intended purpose of this site as per [our FAQ](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). See also [this discussion](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/a/177/109) on our meta site! Also, "[no Stack site allows questions like _'what is your favorite source about ...'_](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/a/232/109)".

Comment: Note: [The moderators discussed this close/reopen issue here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8908576#8908576), and everybody is welcome to join the [chat].

Comment: Per the discussion, I've converted this question to Community Wiki. This means anyone who has additional information to add to the topic should [edit the existing answer](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/7806/420) to include their contribution. The goal of community wiki is to have a **single, comprehensive answer to an important question**.

Comment: I've removed some comments here that offered suggestions, and instead incorporated them into the answer below.

Comment: It has been pointed out that *modern* children's literature may be much less prone to poor female role models than older titles like *Cinderella*. It may be best to reword this question to focus on what types of role models are desired.  Please [join in the discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/conversation/discussion-of-http-parenting-stackexchange-com-questions-7803-what-stories-for) and chime in if you have an opinion.

Comment: Starting a discourse on Cinderella is offtopic I know but I'm not sure I accept the example of this question especially in the respect of Cinderella wanting the status, money & beauty.  She wanted to be released from slavery and go to the party that every other girl in town was invited to... hardly unreasonable or material.  The prince liking her that much was the fairy godmother's magical way to address the injustice she had suffered.

Comment: Pretty much anything Barbie right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The American Library Association is a sponsor of the [Amelia Bloomer project](http://ameliabloomer.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/the-2013-amelia-bloomer-project/), which looks each year for children's literature (both fiction and nonfiction) with strong female characters.

Your local library is a great resource.  Ask the librarians at your local library. They should be able to make some suggestions and recommendations.

It is important to remember that fairy tales operate on many levels - they are archetypal and symbolic, and while we as adults often read them very literally, children are sometimes more open to underlying messages. Put simply (and probably over-simply), we are not meant to associate only with our own gender in the story, but to relate to all characters in the story, irrespective of gender. So when I read Cinderella as a girl, I see myself not only as Cinderella, but as the prince, and the stepmother and the godmother and the stepsisters. I connect with a part of myself that wants to be beautiful, a part that wants to rescue, a part that is jealous and petty, a part that is kind and generous...

### Some specific titles that portray strong female role models:

#### Books

- Author Jane Yolen might be of particular interest to you as she has written many [fairy tales](http://janeyolen.com/works/category/fairy-tales/) that emphasize the strong female character. She is also the author of *[Touch Magic: Fantasy, Faerie and Folklore in the Literature of Childhood](http://janeyolen.com/works/touch-magic/)* which explores the importance of fairy tales and mythology.
- Robert Munsch's [*The Paper Bag Princess*](http://robertmunsch.com/book/the-paper-bag-princess) Take a look at his works and see if something resonates.
- Sun's East, Moon's West by Merrie Haskell inverts the traditional questing prince format for a questing princess. And while I have yet to read [*The Princess Curse*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Princess-Curse-Merrie-Haskell/dp/0062008137/), at least from the description, it looks to be exactly what you're looking for.
- [Mafalda](http://www.quino.com.ar/) hates soup and loves Beatles.  Supercharged with adult attitudes, Mafalda is just too good to ignore.
- Andrew Clements: *The School Story* and *The Landry News*.  The first has a 12-year-old girl who has a determined girl friend (i.e., also passes [Bechdel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test)) who helps her get her novel published.  The second is about the new girl in class who publishes her own newspaper and shakes up the teacher who was in a rut in the process.
- Ellen Klages: *The Green Glass Sea*.  An 11-year-old girl joins her scientist dad in Los Alamos in 1943.
- [Pippi Longstocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippi_Longstocking) is a good rolemodel, because she is not just a strong and independent girl who shows that she doesn't need someone to protect her, she also actively opposes those who try to protect her (by trying to put her in a foster home).
- [*Matilda*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_%28novel%29), by Roald Dahl
- [Coraline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coraline) by Neil Gaiman. The eponymous heorine discovers a strange parallel world in which a warped version of her mother initially attracts her, but then turns out rather sinister.
- Terry Pratchett's [Tiffany Aching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_Aching) series of Discworld books: The Wee Free Men, A Hat Full of Sky, Wintersmith and I Shall Wear Midnight. Can't recommend this enough.
- The [Percy Jackson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_jackson) series by Rick Riordan. Some of the powerful girls in the series include Annabeth Chase (a total genius, despite dyslexia), Thalia Grace (one of the most powerful demigods alive), Clarisse La rue (all the guys fear her) and many, many others.

#### Films

- [The 2012 Pixar film *Brave*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1217209/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)
- [The 1989 film by Hayao Miyazaki *Kiki's Delivery Service*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002ZTQVLG) features a young girl starting her own delivery service on broom!
- [Miyazaki's 1985 *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0001XAPZ6) for older girls (8 and up)
- Other movies by Hayao Miyazaki like *The Cat Returns* or *Spirited Away*.
- [Disney's Mulan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00024I2Z4) which raises the issues you're concerned about
- [1996 film, *Matilda*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_%281996_film%29), based on the book of same title by Roald Dahl.
- [Coraline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coraline_%28film%29), the film version

#### TV

- [The animated series *Avatar: The Last Airbender*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417299/) has Katara & Toph as the two main female characters (for older girls 8 and up)
- [*The Legend of Korra*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1695360/?ref_=fn_al_ch_1a)  (for older girls 8 and up)

#### Websites

- The [A Mighty Girl](http://www.amightygirl.com/) website contains articles and product suggestions for empowering girls of all ages on a wide range of topis. Their Facebook page is also updated daily.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into it. I'm aware that stories can be looked at in several ways; what bothers me is the ubiquity of the subordinate female. I haven't crossed *any* stories so far where a female character is definitely the competent, leading hero.

Comment: Ask the librarians at your local library. They should be able to find you plenty of them.

Comment: Half of these answers are films, I've edited it to separate them out.

Comment: I would add that pretty much most of Miyazaki's films have strong female leads (there are a few exceptions). So definitely look into Miyazaki! Great list! Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippi_Longstocking

Comment: @KelseyRider 'Matilda' by Roald Dahl, also a movie and now a theatrical production is about female leading hero who is not just competent and insubordinate, but rises above small-minded dishonestly and vindictiveness of people surrounding her.

Comment: Don't forget the Book of Esther, Susan in The Chronicles of Narnia is also interesting.

Comment: You might also check out My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic. Almost all the characters are female and most conflicts are caused by outside sources. The main characters are most definitely competent and leading heroines, but there are episodes where one (or sometimes all) of them screw up.

Answer (score 2):

Once your daughters are older, around six or seven or older, introduce them to the Percy Jackson series by Rick Riordan. Some of the powerful girls in the series include Annabeth Chase (a total genius, despite dyslexia), Thalia Grace (one of the most powerful demigods alive), Clarisse La rue (all the guys fear her) and many, many others. There's even a group of immortal teenage girls who swear off boys. There is some romance (in the fifth book) but all the girls can stand on their own two feet and are normally as good, if not better, than the guys at nearly everything. There's nothing rude or inappropriate about these books but they do have a lot going on (you could read these to them at a younger age though)
Also films like Disney's Brave (2012), Mulan (1998), Kung Fu Panda (2008) and St Trinians all feature strong female characters standing up and proving they are strong and independent. In future, when they are older, introduce the Hunger Games since Katniss is a strong fictional charcter.
Most strong female characters are in novels available to the teenage audience though, since younger girls are normally more interested in princesses.

Answer (score 1):

Picture books: Amazing Grace - Miss Rumphius - Outside Over There - "Pish Posh", Said Heironymus Bosch - The Enchanter's Daughter - The Pirate Queen - Trouble With Trolls - Young Guinevere

Chapter books: Gwinna - The Borrowers - The Secret Garden - Caddie Woodlawn - Julie of the Wolves - The 'Little House' books - The Chronicles of Prydain - The Tombs of Atuan - The Changeling - Self-Portrait With Wings

Movies: The Secret of Roan Inish - The Three Lives of Thomasina - Fern Gully - The Secret Garden (1993) - Tangled - Brave - Frozen - Spirited Away - Howl's Moving Castle - The Secret World of Arrietty -

Answer (score -1):

Pollyanna, the leading character of a novel by Eleanor H. Porter is a great role model because she taught kids optimism.